# Is there any advantage to leveling a tower?

Tags: sanctum-2

For example, The Violator takes 300 resources to upgrade each consecutive level. Is there a drastic difference between spending 299 resources on upgrading it vs spending 300 on it, or is it the same as any other 1-resource upgrade? Is the whole "Tower level counter" thing arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got back into this game this year after 5+ years, so I'm here to necro this question. :)

The short answer is... It depends. Many tower attributes scale linearly between levels, but there is sometimes a notable jump in the number if you manage to push it to a new level.

The [Sanctum fan wiki](https://sanctum.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Sanctum_2_towers) has all the data you need to see how things scale, and how big the jumps are. When I came back to playing Sanctum 2 after playing Sanctum 1, I immediately noticed that the game doesn't tell you what the next level stats will actually be, so I guess you just have to memorize the data or keep the wiki open!

Damage and range for the Violator, Gatling and Kairos towers all scale linearly without jumps, so no special considerations are required.

The [Lightning tower](https://sanctum.fandom.com/wiki/Lightning) is an example of a tower where the range suddenly jumps up at level 3. The Scatter Laser, Rocket Tower and Amp Spire have the same attribute.

[image: Stats table for lightning tower]

The [Cannon](https://sanctum.fandom.com/wiki/Cannon) has significant jumps in damage, although this is offset by the reduced fire rate since it fires more rounds per volley. This is a bit of an outlier. In fact, the way these numbers jump from level 1-2 is particularly interesting, as the wiki says, "Because of how its attributes are scaled, a level 1 Cannon that is almost at level 2 deals more damage overall than a level 2 Cannon. However, a level 2 Cannon is significantly more effective against the Armoured Heavy."

[image: Stats table for cannon tower]